# Find all functions $f$ satisfying a certain property

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How can we find all real-valued functions $f$ such that $f^{(n+1)}(x) = f^{(n)}(x)$? The question gives a hint which says: "If $n=2$, then we have $f(x) = ae^x+be^{-x}$, for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. After proving this proceed by induction on $n$." I can see how to complete the proof assuming the hint, but how can I prove that fact?

Clarification: We are not allowed to assume that $f(x) = ae^x+be^{-x}$, but rather need to *show* this when $n = 2$.

Comment: Do you have to find them all?  What if you simply claim that $f$ is a function having that property

Comment: Should that be $f^{(n)},$ instead of $f^n$?

Comment: Yes it should be. Thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Take $f(x) = ae^x + be^{-x}$.  If $n$ is odd, then $f^{(n)}(x) = ae^x - be^{-x}$.  If $n$ is even, then $f^{(n)}(x) = ae^x + be^{-x}$, which shows that $b = 0$ (since the derivative of $e^{-x}$ depends on its order).  Therefore, $f(x) = ae^{x}$, where $a$ is any value.

I don't think there are any sophisticated method to prove that $f$ is of the form $ae^{x}$, where $a$ is an arbitrary constant.

Answer (score 0):

Setting $g=f^{(n)}$, we have $g'=g$, i.e. $g(x)=be^x$, where $b$ is a real constant. Thus
$$
f^{(n)}(x)=be^x,
$$
and we deduce that
$$
f(x)=be^x+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kx^k,
$$
with $a_0,\ldots,a_{n-1}\in \mathbb{R}$.